# Comparing strings on delphi get error incompatible types

Tags: delphi

I have this code:

```
if (conexao.FieldValues['complex'] = '02' and conexao.FieldValues['financ'] = '04') then
```

The `conexao.FieldValues['complex']` is a string and '02' is a string too, but I get an error:

> Incompatible types: 'string' and 'Boolean'

Why?

Comment: if ((conexao.FieldValues['complex'] = '02') and (conexao.FieldValues['financ'] = '04'))

Comment: You need to wrap each test in parentheses: `if (conexao.FieldValues['complex'] = '02') and (conexao.FieldValues['financ'] = '04')`

Comment: it's works, thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Order of operations means `=` is evaluated after `and`. You need to use `()` to force the evaluation in the order you intend.

[image]